# How do I use FTP via VIM?

Tags: vim, ftp

I have been trying to ftp into a shared hosting account with vim (brand new to vim) for a few hours now. I read about this syntax but I have no idea how to use it apparently or where do I insert my ftp password.

```
:e ftp://[user@]machine/path
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vim ftp://username@yourdomain.com//the/path/to/yourfile.php
```

Note: Double Slashes after machine/domain name.

**Edit:**
You can also Try this Plugin.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to do

```
:Nread ftp://yourusername@yoursite.com/
```

notice the slash at the end it's important